# Mongoid/mongodb indexing

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am implementing a ruby on rails app with mongodb/mongoid and I am bit confused about the better indexing/searching structure.
I have a field `staff` in a model and a staff can be either of type - production, broker, office.
Each staff is a `Person`. Each type can have multiple staff.

So I have two approaches:

1). Make `staff as an array` and store it like

> `[{:key => 'broker', :name => "Broker Name", :person_id => "654978"},
>
>   {:key => 'office', :name => "Office Staff 1", :person_id => "564654"},
>
>   {:key => 'office', :name => 'another office', :person_id => '79878'}]`

2). Make is a `Hash` and store is as
    `{:brokers => [{:person_id =>
    2134, :name => 'Broker 1'}],

  :office =>> [{:person_id =>
    2131, :name => 'Office 1'}, {:person_id => 1231, :name => 'Office
    2'}]}`

I want to index these documents and should be able to search documents like, where office = '465456'.

Comment: Don't know why people simply down vote without commenting about whats wrong... :(

Comment: what is "office = 465456"?   Is that the person_id?  It's hard to tell exactly what your intention is, I'm guessing this could be contributing to down-vote.

Comment: Lately, there seems to have been a real rampage of downvoting (without comment) perfectly reasonable questions that have the Mongoid tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store it as a hash you need several indexes. Since you then have to index the office name for each of the keys in the hash. If you store it as an array you only need 1 index.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you really want to store *multiple* indices; @bjartek is right, you'll want to store these as arrays:

```
class Office
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :people, as: :staff

  # unsure for polymorphic embeds; perhaps this needs 'staff.name'
  index "people.name"
  index "people.person_id"
  index "people.key"
end
```

http://mongoid.org/docs/indexing.html